# PHP regex matches and include groups in each match (full match)

Tags: php, regex

Basically, my variable contains html code and within that there is a url I try to capture.
I am able to capture it but I forgot which flags or methods includes the groups into matches

```
  $xxx = 'icon-2525 attributeIcon-2521" focusable="false" height="100%" role="img" 
  width="100%"><use xlink:href="#icon-clipboard"></use></svg><dl class="itemAttribute-1524"><dd 
  class="attributeValue-3783238563"><a class="attributeLink-387024144" rel=" noopener noreferrer" 
  href="https://tld.example.com/en/main?id=325235231763265&amp;ref=testetghe" 
  title="Opens in a new window." target="_blank"';

preg_match_all("/https:\/\/tld.example.com(.*?)ref=testetghe\"/is", $xxx, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $url);
```

foreach will correctly set $url to (/en/main?id=325235231763265&amp)  but I want the `$url` to be the complete url  (https://tld.example.com/en/main?id=325235231763265&ref=testetghe)

what would I do ? Is it a flag I have to change? I tried so many on regex101
Here its working
https://regex101.com/r/jguNDZ/1

But I want the Full Match output . Thank you so much
[image]
Thank you

Comment: it's funny when your name is `DOMDocument`, but uses regex to parse HTML, use the index zero to get the match

Comment: thanks Kevin but the variable may also contain xml, csv, tab seperated, hyperloop, dataheaders etc

Answer (score 0):

When you use `preg_match_all`. You will have all values ​​that match your regex. After using `print_r($matches)`, you will see the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://tld.example.com/en/main?id=325235231763265&amp;ref=testetghe"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => /en/main?id=325235231763265&amp;
        )

)
```

So, you need to use `$matches[0]` instead of `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the complete url , then use **preg_match** function and get the match at 0 index of the matches.

```
$div = 'icon-2525 attributeIcon-2521" focusable="false" height="100%" role="img" 
width="100%"><use xlink:href="#icon-clipboard"></use></svg><dl class="itemAttribute-1524"><dd 
class="attributeValue-3783238563"><a class="attributeLink-387024144" rel=" noopener noreferrer" 
href="https://tld.example.com/en/main?id=325235231763265&amp;ref=testetghe" 
title="Opens in a new window." target="_blank"';

$pattern = '/https:\/\/tld.example.com(.*?)ref=testetghe\"/is';
preg_match( $pattern, $div, $matches);

var_dump( $matches[0] );
```